# angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in angularJS 1.5.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load my own module, it worked with first module but facing error when I tried to add another module. See below files:

**app.js**

```
var gcApp = angular.module('gcApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'gcApp.controllers',
    'gcApp.services'

]);

gcApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .state('farmer-home', {
            url: '/farmer-home',
            templateUrl: 'views/farmer-home.html',
            //controller: 'farmerCtrl'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        });

});
```

**controller.js**

```
'use strict';
/* Controllers */
var controllers = angular.module('gcApp.controllers', [
        'login-controller',
        'farmer-controller'
    ]);
```

**farmer-controller.js**

```
'use strict';

var farmerController = angular.module('farmer-controller', []);

farmerController.controller('farmerCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    console.log("Farmer controller..");

});
```

**service.js**

```
'use strict';
/* Services */
var services = angular.module('gcApp.services', [
        'login-service',
        'farmer-service'
        ]);
```

**farmer-service.js**

```
'use strict';

var farmerService = angular.module('farmer-service', []);

farmerService.service('FarmerManagementService', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    console.log("FarmerManagementService");
});
```

At the first there was only login-controller in controllers and login-service in    services. It is running smoothly. But when I added farmer-controller in controllers and farmer-service in services it is showing the above error. 
I have no idea why this is happening.

Conceptually I have added farmer-controller module into controllers and for service. So I am wondering why it is failed to load every time. At which point I am doing the wrong thing.

**Angular version I am using is 1.5.6**

Comment: It was a silly mistake from my side. I forgot to add new js files in index.html

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var controllers = angular.module('gcApp.controllers', [
    'login-controller',
    'farmer-controller',
]);
```

to

```
var controllers = angular.module('gcApp.controllers', [
    'login-controller',
    'farmer-controller'
]);
```

and also

```
var services = angular.module('gcApp.services', [
    'login-service',
    'farmer-service',
    ]);
```

to

```
var services = angular.module('gcApp.services', [
    'login-service',
    'farmer-service'
    ]);
```

and try again. there should not be comma after last dependancy.

Comment: I am sorry but commas has been removed before posting. I will update the question.